# How to remotely connect to a macbook from another macbook

Tags: macos, remote-desktop

I am a web developer.  I am running on osx lion.  A coworker, who runs snow leopard, found a bug in a feature that implemented that occurs only on his version of safari.  The bug does not occur in mine.

I want to debug the issue on his computer without kicking him off his computer every 2 minutes when I make a change to my code.  Is there a way that I can set up an account on his computer and remotely connect to it without interfering with any work he's doing?

I need GUI control, while at the same time not taking GUI control from him.  THIS MEANS NO VNC.  I also would like a free solution if one exists.  I've been googling for a while now, but i feel like i am not hitting the correct search terms.

Comment: I don't think this is possible if your coworker's on Snow Leopard, because native multi-user screensharing was only added in Lion: http://appleinsider.com/articles/11/03/31/mac_os_x_10_7_lion_to_introduce_multi_user_screen_sharing.html

Comment: i am not looking for screensharing.  What i am looking for is to log into a user account he created for me remotely, and have access to the gui, without interfering with what he is doing.

Comment: I think screensharing *is* what you want, but unfortunately the "share the screen of a separate user account on a remote machine without affecting the currently logged in user" feature is only available in Lion. From the article I linked to: *"In Mac OS X 10.7 Lion, the built-in Screen Sharing feature, updated from 1.1.1 to version 1.3, now allows remote users to log into a separate user account from the one that is currently logged in. That means that while one user is logged into a machine, a second user can login to the same machine remotely, seeing their own desktop and user environment."*

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this could work but, as you're stick on this, you may try access your coworker's Mac through SSH and try using the *open* command (see the *man* pages for the opportune arguments).